# Calculated fields in Laravel and general PHP

Tags: php, laravel, testing, design-patterns, phpunit

In Laravel / PHP its easy to create accessors and mutators to transform or create dynamic fields from a database.

Although its too easy to duplicate this same logic throughout your app, when you are not accessing the same data through an ORM model (e.g. direct queries).

`$order->totalPlusTax; // (total * 10%)`

The logic to calculate this field should be written once, testable and NOT tied into an ORM.

**What are best practices or design patterns around this logic?**

Comment: create a helper function and pass `(total, percent)` as a parameter and call the function where you wants.

Comment: Sure that the obvious solution. Although on a large scale app, helper functions also become unmanageable. The answer I'm looking for is more "design patterns" based with community agreed principals.

Comment: Your question is just really unclear. I don't understand what you are looking for. If you want to know how to stop duplicating logic, then refactoring and good class design is the answer.

Comment: Looking for an answer with detailed analysis of a community agreed design pattern. e.g factories, repositories, singletons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design patterns have evolved as a way to organise and provide performance gains to our code. They often address very specific issues. Your question is so broad that almost any design pattern will solve it to some degree.

For example, if you have logic which checks a database for certain conditions before creating an object, this will live in that objects factory class and nowhere else. If you have logic which finds an object by checking conditions in the database, then this logic would live in the repository class and nowhere else.

The solution to your problem isn't one particular design pattern. It is solved by many design patterns, by OO classes and methods, and by following SOLID principles.

**Side note:**

I'm sorry if this is not the answer you were expecting. I actually found myself in a similar position a few years ago when I started studying design patterns and community best practices.

The issue I think we sometimes have as coders is that we apply our logical minds too literally to everything. When I was looking into design patterns and best practices I would often spend days trying to work out what was the correct way to implement something. The answer to this is not design patterns or community best practices. The answer is:

> The correct code to write is the code that makes a test pass, where that test validates some value is being delivered to the business.

I'm not saying just write any old code, but you very often dont know what design patterns to use until you start writing some code. So the best place to start is to write the code that makes your application work: Kent Beck's advise on this:

> Make it work, make it right, make it fast.

The "make it right" part is where you refactor code out into design patterns etc. You need to look at your code base and see where there are common elements. Often its just a case of refactoring out common logic into a class or method. Sometimes it will be to use the design patterns you have mentioned.

Obviously there are times when you have a pretty good idea of the end solution and can use design patterns up front (Active Record, MVC etc) but in your case it seems like you will only know once you start seeing some duplicate logic. I'm afraid its then just a case of looking at a few design patterns and seeing if they work for you, but I would say just refactor the common code out into a separate class or method. That is the community best practice you are looking for.

Comment: And that's the best answer I could ask for with such a question :)